# Prove that there is no isomorphism between the groups of matrices of a size n with determinant 1 and matrices of a size n with determinant +1/-1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

We look at the group of all real matrices nxn with det(A) = 1 with matrix multiplication operation and the group of all real matrices nxn with det(A) = 1 or -1 also with multiplication. We need to prove there's no isomorphism here. I need a general proof for matrices of any size.

So far I was only able to prove this for the matrices of nxn where n is odd. We take a matrix nxn with det(A)=1 which has 2^n square roots. It has 2^(n-1) roots which have det(B) = 1 and 2^(n-1) roots with det(B) = -1. So if we look at an image of an equation A=B*B it has to have 2^(n-1) square roots. Suppose it does, then we look at f(A), it has det(f(A)) = 1 and 2^(n-1) roots. 2^(n-2) of them have det = 1. We look at an image of f(A)=C*C. It has to have  2^(n-2) roots. Let's repeat this process until we find no matrix with 2^k square roots. At this point equation A=B*B and it's image have different amount of roots, which implies there's no isomorphism.

This method does not work for matrices of even size though, since I can't claim that if a matrix has k square roots, then exactly half of them are positive. So I believe we need to investigate how many square roots can a matrix have. I have made a different question for that, the link is here [How many real square roots can a real invertible matrix have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585620/how-many-real-square-roots-can-a-real-invertible-matrix-have)

Comment: Hi, write down what you have found already or what you have tried. People here will give you recommendations or hint but rarely a full proof of what you ask for.. especially if you don’t even take the time to do some research on your own

Comment: What is the field here? Not $\mathbb{F}_2$, I guess?

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the question with my recent researches on this topic. I hope it's more more clear now

Comment: Shorter proof for $n$ odd: the [centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)) are respectively $\{I_n\}$ and $\{\pm I_n\}.$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [commutator subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) of these two groups $SL_n(\Bbb R)$ and $SL_n(\Bbb R)⋊\{\pm1\}$ are both $SL_n(\Bbb R),$ so the two groups cannot be isomorphic.